# delete multiple rows using php array

Tags: php, mysql

```
$ids = $_POST['ids'];

// sky***earth***sea***sun***...

$ids = explode("***", $ids);

foreach ($ids as $id) {
    $st = $db->query("delete from tags where id = " . $id);
}
```

Is there a more elegant way to delete multiple rows, especially regarding peformances in case of huge array? Something like:

```
$st = $db->query("delete from tags where id in " . $ids);
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17657760/mysql-delete-multiple-row-in-array. On top of that, your code is vulnerable to SQL Injections, please learn about them here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Comment: @Paul, on client side there is no any input, just user click event. Is the code still vulnerable to sql injeciton?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Better method to delete multiple rows in a MySQL database with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8542737/better-method-to-delete-multiple-rows-in-a-mysql-database-with-php)

Comment: @bonaca you are using the superglobal $_POST. There is no need for any form in the frontend. I can just send a POST request to that specific file and my payload in ids will be passed to the query without any filtering, escaping or something related.

Comment: If your `id` is a text column i.e. `sky`, `earth` etc Then the `$id` needs to be wrapped in quotes like `$st = $db->query("delete from tags where id = '$id' ");` **But do pay heed to the [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
Use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace the exploded *** with a comma(,)

```
$st = $db->query("delete from tags where id in (" . implode(",", explode("***", $ids)) .")");
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17657893/5837918

Answer (score 1):

$kk= '';  foreach ($ids as $id) {  $kk.=$id. ',';  } $kk = rtrim($kk, ','); $st = $db->query("delete from tags where id In($kk))";